# Cross compile Python 2.7.16 for armel (32-bit)

Tags: debian, ssh, python, compiling, gcc

I have a device with armel architecture, the file system is running on a VM (amd64 architecture) because the device has not enough space to install compile requirements. The OS is Debian 9 (stretch).

I download the Python, create the file config.site with following content (found it in another answer):

```
ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no
ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no
```

After that i run `./configure`. At last with many options (that i found in different forums) like:

```bsh
CONFIG_SITE=config.site ./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32" --build=armel --enable-ipv6
```

At this point, for what i need `--[dis|en]able-ipv6`?

With different settings it work, if it worked I run `make`.
If this was complete i run

```bsh
checkinstall -D --install=no --fstrans=yes
```

If this running successful i install the .deb package on the another device with armel architecure, but if I run `python` there comes an error: `bash: /usr/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file`.
Can you explain me why?

***UPDATE***
After the installation of the Debian package the output of `file /usr/local/bin/python`is a symbolic link up to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.
The output of the last is:

```bsh
python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

I found that the gcc use x86-64 to compile is that correct? Or i need to change that? When yes, how i change that?

I want to know more about compiling. Please write detailed answers and/or add source links to your answer.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Debian 9 `python2.7` package for `armel` not appropriate?

Comment: Please show the output of `file /usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: StephenKitt: Where I can see this? The python version 2.7.6 works fine as well.

@JigglyNaga: Oh I forgot to write it into the question. I'm currently not on the computer. But i know the command says me it was compiled for x86-64.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201282/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/74145/173666

Answer (score 1):

Compiling is the process of translating a language such as C into instructions for a CPU.  Different CPUs have different instruction sets. Think of this as x86_64 being a different CPU language to armel.

While it's technically possible to make a compiler that can write in any instruction set (language), I don't believe there are any that can just switch.

So to use GCC to compile for armel you need a copy of GCC which itself was compiled to write armel.  Here's the catch... To achieve what you are trying you need a copy of GCC which will compile for armel, but that copy of GCC needs to run on (be compiled for) x86_64.  This is known as a cross compiler: a compiler who's code is compiled for one instruction set that will, when used compile code to a different instruction set.

The compiler you will need is `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` (https://packages.debian.org/buster/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi).  You may find that this get's tripped up with header files (compiling will fail on `# include <...>`), or libraries (`undefined reference to ...`).  I'm afraid it's so long since I've done this I can't actually remember how to tell the compiler to use the headers and libraries from your target system.  This may be something you need to research.

Comment: First, thanks for the description. There is a large list if i run the command. And I found `libgcc1-armel-cross`. Now I run `make CC=libgcc1-armel-cross` but that throw an error: `Makefile:676: recipe for target 'Modules/python.o' failed`

Comment: The one you want is `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`.

Comment: This i tried as well. But i get the same error. Is there perhaps something wrong with the command `./configure`?

Comment: I'm afraid this is rapidly going beyond my knowledge, I'm not going to be able to help you much further.  I will say the error you've mentioned should have more information before it. As my edit suggests, I'm half expecting you to have a problem with headers or libraries, but I can't for the life of me remember how to re-configure this.  Double check if `configure` has a `--target` option.  You might need to set this instead of `CC`.  Sorry I can't do more.